# how can I change the JAlert colour based on the response type

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, alert

I am using JAlert inside my asp.net mvc web application as follow:-

```
function createfail(data) {
    jAlert('Error Occured.' + data.description);
}

function createsuccess(data) {
    jAlert('Record was added Successfully', 'Creation Confirmation');
}
```

Currently I have two functions which return jAlerts as shown above, one is raises if the Create operation is success, while the other fire if the Create operation fail. But I am facing the following problems:-

1. I need to differentiate these two alerts by colour, so if it is success to have it blue, if it fail to have its color as Red.
2. Also if it is success to automatically close the Jalert after a spcifc time, while if it is an error to keep displaying it, until the user close it .

Can anyone advice how I can achive this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some customization on jAlert as well.
You might check this link: http://beckelman.net/2008/12/30/jquery-alert-dialogs/

It's pretty much what you look for.

Regards